# Restriction of Co-Ordinates in the Product Topology

Tags: general-topology

I have been reading John B. Conway's book, but *A Course in Point Set Topology,* and am stuck pondering over a statement made:

> Since the subbase only restricts one coordinate, neighborhoods of a point in a product topology only restrict a finite number of coordinates.

Here he is talking of the product topology and the standard subbase.

What does he mean by restriction of one coordinate? How does this imply the conclusion on neighborhoods?

I know that the product topology is the weak topology defined by the product of a collection of topological spaces by the projection maps.

Please help me in understanding this statement, thank you very much!

Comment: Think about the inverse image of an open set under the projection map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $T$ is $any$ topology on $P=\prod_{i\in I}X_i$  such that each projection $\rho_j$ (for each $j\in I$) is continuous, where $\rho_j((x_i)_{i\in I})=x_j$ when $(x_i)_{i\in I}\in P.$

So if $U_j$ is an open subset of $X_j$ then $\rho_j^{-1}U_j \in T.$

Now $\rho_j^{-1}U_j=\prod_{i\in I}V_i,$ where $V_j=U_j,$ and if $j\ne i\in I$ then $V_i=X_i.$ ("Restriction of one co-ordinate").

Consider the family $F$ of all $\rho_j^{-1}(U_j)$ over all $j\in I$ and all open $U_j\subset X_j.$ We have $F\subset T$ so  $B=\{\cap G: G\subset F\land G \text { is finite}\} \subset T.$

Every member of $B$ is of the form $\prod_{i\in I} W_i$ where each $W_i$ is open in $X_i, $ and $\{i\in I: W_i\ne X_i\}$ is finite. ("Restriction of only finitely many co-ordinates").

But $B$ is a base (basis) for a topology $T^*$ on $P$ (because $\cup B=P,$ and if $b_1,b_2\in B$ then $b_1\cap b_2\in B$). So we must have $T\supset T^*.$ And each $\rho_j$ is continuous with respect to $T^*.$ So $T^*$ is the $\subset$-smallest (i.e. weakest ) topology on $P$ such that each $\rho_j$ is continuous. It is called the (Tychonoff) product topology on $P.$

If $p\in N\subset P$ where $N$ is a nbhd of $p$ in the product topology then $p\in b\subset N$ for some $b\in B.$ That is $p\in \prod_{i\in I}W_i\subset N$ where each $W_i$ is open in $X_i$ but $\{i\in I:W_i\ne X_i\}$ is finite.

Comment: Thank you so much, this explains so much!